# Creating a new string literal type based on another

Tags: css, typescript, typescript-generics

The CSS.Pseudo types of csstypes have a bunch of CSS selectors like for ':hover' , ':active' and so on.

Is it possible to create a new type based on CSS.Pseudo, which accepts all the CSS.Pseudo types but with a '&' in front?

For example '&:hover', '&:active' and so on.

I want to be able to do something like

```
type CSS.Pseudo = ':hover' | ':active' ... etc.

type CssStyle= { [SOMETHINGSOMETHING CSS.Pseudo]: string}

const styles: CssStyle= {
    '@:hover: someCssString, //OK
    ':hover:  someCssString,  //NOT OK
    '&:hov':  someCssString   //NOT OK
}
```

I've tried a billion things on TS Playground but I feel I'm just not good enough at TS or it's just impossible.

Comment: Why do this with Union Types, it seems like an Enum would provide more benefits (`Pseudo.Hover` and `Pseudo.Active` etc).

Comment: @ErikPhilips Thats just how CSS.Pseudo is written https://www.npmjs.com/package/csstype

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this programmatically, at least as of TypeScript 3.5.

This has been [suggested](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12940) before, and the suggestion was closed as a duplicate of either a [string literal key augmentation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754) or a [regular expression string literal validation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579) suggestion, neither of which are particularly close to being incorporated into the language.  If you really want to see this happen, you might want to go to one or both of those issues and give them a  or possibly describe your use case if you think it's more compelling than what's already there.

Sorry this isn't the answer you probably want, but at least you can stop trying to get the compiler to do this for you.  Good luck!